# React Router dom change history without changing the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In simple words, I need to know whether react router dom has something like `History.pushState()`

***Detailed***

I have a component which will have intial url of `/home/1/1`. Everytime user clicks on a button the route should change to `/home/1/2`, `/home/1/3`. And I need it to re-render according to the change in path. I can't figure it out. Now, I think `History.pushState()` may work, but still wondering is there any other solution, with or without react router dom

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render your component depending on the route, then doing a `history.push()` is the correct solution.

If you are using a functional component, then consider using the `useHistory` hook to retrieve the history in order to push the new route (see [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)), and the `useParams` hook to retrieve the route parameters (see [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)).

If you are using a class component, then you can wrap your component in the `withRouter` higher-order component to access the history and to retrieve the parameters (see [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that route of your component which needs to be re-rendered is defined like "home/1/:id" in the path attribute of Route component, For eg.

In the YourComponent, you can trap into router props and you can add that as a dependeny to the useEffect. You can use "useParams" hook as well to retrive the params object.

```
 const YourComponent = (routerProps) =>{

 useEffect(()=>{
  //your logic
 }, [routerProps.params.id])

}
```